# a = x+ 1/x, b= x- 1/x. How can I Prove that a/b is not Equal to 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I prove that - a/b is not equal to 1. While:-

a = x+ 1/x -- **Not - *(x+1)/x*** 
b = x- 1/x -- **Not - *(x-1)/x***

HOW TO PROVE?   (I know that '1' will never be the Answer, But HOW could I prove?)

Comment: $\frac {a}{b} = 1 \implies a = b$

Comment: it'sp pretty obvious that it's not equal to 1 but the limit of the ratio does tend to 1 for big values of $x$

Comment: Please don't just slap any tag including the word 'algebra' on your question. It's been removed now.

Comment: Note that it can be equal to 1 in some exotic fields (like the field of nimbers)

Comment: Ohh, Sorry for adding much Tags, But i really did not knew that this problem was a part of "Precalculus" as I am just a Grade 7 Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by contradiction:

Suppose there is an $x$ such that $\frac {a}{b}= 1$

$\frac {a}{b}= 1 \implies a = b\\
x + \frac 1x = x - \frac 1x\\
\frac 1x = -\frac 1x$

This would suggest $\frac 1x = 0$ which is an impossibility.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to \infty}$${1\over x}=0$
$\Rightarrow$${1\over x}=-{1\over x}$
$\Rightarrow$$x^2+{1\over x}=x^2-{1\over x}$

Neglecting ${\infty}$, ${1\over x}\neq0$
Which means ${1\over x}\neq-{1\over x}$
$\Rightarrow$$x^2+{1\over x}\neq x^2-{1\over x}$